# GithubのMarkdownでdetails、summaryタグ内のリンクから日本語のセクションへのジャンプをどう作成するか？

Tags: github, markdown

Github上で、あるMarkdownファイル内のdetails、summaryタグ内にリンクを作り、そこから別のMarkdownファイル内の特定のセクション（セクションのタイトルが日本語）へのジャンプを作成できない問題に直面しています。以下は試してみたコードスニペットです：

ジャンプ元.md

```
<details>
  <summary>(クリック)</summary>
  [概要](../pathToジャンプ先.md#概要)
</details>
```

ジャンプ先.md

```
## 概要
```

このスニペットは、ジャンプ先.mdという、ジャンプ元.mdとは別のMarkdownファイル内の「概要」というセクションにリンクすることを意図しています。しかし、リンクをクリックしてもドキュメント先へも#概要でタグ付けされた特定のセクションにもスクロールしません。

以下を試みましたが、いずれも問題の解決までは至りませんでした：

Markdownでの直接リンク: タグの外に直接Markdownリンクを使用してみましたが、それでも日本語のセクションタイトルにナビゲートしません。(※英語でジャンプ先を書き、ジャンプ元を#英語で書き換えればナビゲートできますが、日本語でナビゲートしたいです。)

HTML ID属性: ターゲットドキュメント内にHTML構文を使用して手動でid属性を設定してみました（例: `<h2 id="concept">概要</h2>`）が、ターゲットドキュメントにはジャンプしますが、ターゲットセクションにはスクロールしませんでした。

アドバイスや解決策をご教示お願い致します。

Comment: ASCII(7bit)以外の文字を使ったファイル名のリンク表現やアンカータグは%エンコーディングが必要なのだと思われます。GitHubではないですがJupyterlabの記事。[Anchors Are Not Working for Japanese heading #12402](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12402) 記事にはURLの仕様がそうなっているというので、GitHubでも同様に解釈・実装していることが考えられます。試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: `#`以下の部分を削除した場合、ドキュメント先へは飛びますか？ドキュメント先へも飛ばないというと、そもそもリンクのパスなどが間違っている可能性があります。少なくとも、質問の書き方では、今のファイルのあるディレクトリの上のディレクトリにある「pathToジャンプ先.md」を行こうとして、「ジャンプ先.md」には行きません。

Comment: @raccy ご回答ありがとうございます。はい、detailsタグ、summaryタグ外に[概要](../pathToジャンプ先.md#概要)を書くとドキュメント先には飛びます。

Comment: @kunif ご回答ありがとうございます。  
以下の通り、%エンコーディングして試してみましたが、ジャンプ先## 概要でも、概要(## によりジャンプできないと思いテスト)でも該当ページまではジャンプしますが、その後、該当箇所まではスクロールされませんでした。

■パターン1
<details>
  <summary>(クリック)</summary>
  <a href="../pathToジャンプ先.md#%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81"> 概要 </a>
</details>

■パターン2
[概要](../pathToジャンプ先.md#%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

#### 手順

1. Github上で見出しにマウスを合わせるとリンクアイコンが表示されます。このリンクを別ページで開きます。
2. 別ページ内のURLの末尾に#アンカーIDとあるので、アンカーIDをコピーします。
3. コピーしたアンカーIDを#の隣に貼り付けます。

例）

```html
<a href="../該当ファイル.md#アンカーID">概要</a>
```